# How to get testng class parameter in DataProvider

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng

I have in testng.xml parameter in class section like that. In prepare test in dataProvider i want to get `serviceParameter` to get parameter i use `ITestContext` but it only show parameters that are in test node.

How to get parameter in class?

```html
<class name="project.tests.application.ModulesTest">
 <parameter name="serviceParameter" value="MDM"/>
 <methods>
  <include name="checkModule"/>
 </methods>
</class>
```

```
//DataProvider class
@DataProvider(name = "testModuleData")
public static Object[][] testModuleData(ITestContext context, Method method) throws Exception 
{
    try 
    {
        Map<String, String> parameters = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getLocalParameters();
        log.info(parameters);

        [..]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have your parameter available throughout the class then you can define it at the suite level and initialize it in @beforeclass

```
<suite name="Default suite" thread-count="5" group-by-instances="false" verbose="1" allow-return-values="false" parallel="none" data-provider-thread-count="10" junit="false" configfailurepolicy="skip" preserve-order="true" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false">
  <parameter name="testParam" value="test123"/>
  ...
  ...
```

In your test class

```
@BeforeClass
  @Parameters({"testParam"})
  public void init(String suiteParam) {
    this.suiteParam = suiteParam;
  }




 @DataProvider(name = "testDataProvider")
  public Object[][] createData1() {
      String testParam = suiteParam;
      int theNums[][] = new int[][] {{10,20},{100,110}};
      return new Object[][] {
       { testParam, theNums }

  };

  }



  @Test(dataProvider = "testDataProvider") 

  public  void testingParam( String DPparam1, int[][] DPparam2) {

      System.out.println("xml param from @beforeclass param through data provider:  " + DPparam1);
      System.out.println("xml param from @beforeclass without DP: " + suiteParam);
      System.out.println("configured param from data provider: " + DPparam2[0][0]);
      }



      @Test
public  void testingParam2( ) {

      System.out.println("xml param from @beforeclass in different method: " + suiteParam);
      }
```

the above prints

```
xml param from @beforeclass param through data provider:  test123
xml param from @beforeclass without DP: test123
configured param from data provider: 10
xml param from @beforeclass in different method: test123
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your `@Test` annotation, add a `@Parameters` annotation, and then in your Test method add a parameter that is a datatype of String.

For example your TestNG file would be something like this:

```
 <test name="IETest">

        <parameter name="browser" value="ie" />

        <classes>

            <class name="Tests" />
        </classes>
    </test>
```

And your test would look like this:

```
@Parameters("browser")
    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeTest(String browser) {

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/IEDriverServer.exe");

            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/geckodriver.exe");

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();


        }

        driver.get(URL);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
```

Comment: Its not posible tu use @Parameters and DataProvider in the same class and i have many data . So i have to use DataProvider.